# Using vSphere VI Java API to get annotation notes

Tags: java, vmware, vsphere

Anyone have a snippet of how to use the vSphere VI Java API to extract the values in the 'Annotations' section of the 'Summary' tab for a VM? I have looked around a lot as well as combed through the API docs but haven't seen it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API Documentation of [VirtualMachineConfigSpec](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.ConfigSpec.html) first .

Then you can do this from java

```
VirtualMachineConfigSpec configSpec = new VirtualMachineConfigSpec();
configSpec.setAnnotation = "Your annotation string here" 
reconfigVM_Task(vmMOR, configSpec);
```

Comment: This looks good for setting the annotations, but i just want to read what's already there

Comment: Read the documentation http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.ConfigInfo.html

You can retrieve annotation by doing this `vm.getConfig().annotation`

Answer (score 0):

I did this in Perl SDK, but re-doing it to use Java API should be easy.
You get the annotations from [Virtual Machine object](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.VirtualMachine.html#field_detail) which has property named **summary** of class *VirtualMachineSummary* which has **config** of class *VirtualMachineConfigSummary* which has a **annotation** field of type *string* which is what you need.

```
my $vmname = "vmname you are looking for";
# Get all VMs
my $vms = Vim::find_entity_views(
        view_type => 'VirtualMachine',
        filter => {"config.name" => qr/^$vmname$/i},
);

# Iterate over the VMs, getting their annotations
foreach my $vm (@{ $vms }) {
  my $notes = $vm->summary->config->annotation;
  my $name = $vm->summary->config->name;
  if (not defined $notes) {
    print " - VM: $name  has no notes\n";
  }
  elsif ($notes =~ m/^\$*/) {
    print " - VM: $name  has empty notes\n";
  }
  else {
    print " - VM: $name  notes: '$notes'\n";
  }
}
```

Here is the full code: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2613855#2613855